# shared library with Undefined Behavior Sanitizer (clang++)

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, undefined-behavior

I have a problem while running an executable file with dlopen function used to open shared and sanitized library with a one simple function.

**I use precompiled Clang 3.9.0 for Ubuntu 14.04.**

**My question is:** Is it possible to run it properly, so I can look for undefined behavior errors in the library while running an executable ? If the answers is yes, then how ?

I have two files:

```
//simpledll.cpp
#include <cstdio>

int hehe(int argc) {
      int k = 0x7fffffff;
        k += argc;
          return 0;
}

//dlopen.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    void* handle;

    handle = dlopen("simpledll.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if(!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    }

    int (*function)(int) = reinterpret_cast<int (*)(int)> (dlsym(handle, "_Z4hehei"));

    if (function == nullptr)
        fprintf(stderr, "Nope\n");
    else
        function(1000); // this yields signed integer overflow

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to get it to work in two steps (both have failed)

**Step I**

Compile the executable with:

```
clang++ dlopen.cpp -ldl --std=c++11 -o dlopen
```

Compile the library with:

```
clang++ -fsanitize=undefined -shared -o simpledll.so -fPIC simpledll.cpp
```

Result:

```
./dlopen: symbol lookup error: simpledll.so: undefined symbol: __ubsan_handle_add_overflow
```

**Step II** (idea from this [forum](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/fsanitize-undefined-and-shared-libraries-td4029561.html))

Compile the executable as in **Step I**,

Compile the library with:

```
clang++ -fsanitize=undefined -shared -Wl,--whole-archive -L/usr/local/lib/clang/3.9.0/lib/linux/ -lclang_rt.ubsan_standalone_cxx-x86_64 -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lclang_rt.ubsan_standalone-x86_64 -Wl,--no-whole-archive -o simpledll.so -fPIC simpledll.cpp
```

Result:

```
==11478==Sanitizer CHECK failed: /home/development/llvm/3.9.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_init.cc:61 ((UBSAN_MODE_UNKNOWN)) != ((ubsan_mode)) (0, 0)
```

Note that in **Step II**, if we substitute the function in the shared library with the one that has no undefined behavior code, the program runs without a *CHECK failed* error. This indicates that **UBSAN has found an undefined behavior code, however it was unable to report it properly.**

Regards,

Jaszczur

Comment: What would constitute a proper report?

Comment: We should get a runtime error: signed integer overflow, as the number 1000 + 0x7fffffff cannot be represented in type 'int'.

Comment: It looks likee linking sanitizers to shared libraries is not supported in clang. You can compile shared lib code with -fsznitize=... but you need to link the *executable* with the sanitizer runtime (-lclang_rt.ubsan_standalone-x86_64). Once you do that (with -Wl,-whole-archive) you get proper reporting.

Comment: Could you elaborate? When I compile the library like in Step II and executabe with:
clang++ dlopen.cpp -Wl,--whole-archive -L/usr/local/lib/clang/3.9.0/lib/linux/ -lclang_rt.ubsan_standalone_cxx-x86_64 -Wl,--no-whole-archive -ldl --std=c++11 -o dlopen

I still can't get it to work, getting a lot of undefined reference to __ubsan::*

Comment: You need to link libclang_rt.ubsan_standalone-x86_64.a (no cxx in the name).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Now I get a lot of undefined reference like `pthread_getattr_np', where pthread prefix is always present.

Comment: These come from libpthread, -lpthread will take care of them

Comment: clang++ dlopen.cpp -Wl,--whole-archive -L/usr/local/lib/clang/3.9.0/lib/linux/ -lclang_rt.ubsan_standalone-x86_64 -Wl,--no-whole-archive -ldl -lpthread -lrt --std=c++11 -o dlopen

gives me

==3827==Sanitizer CHECK failed: /home/development/llvm/3.9.0/final/llvm.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/ubsan/ubsan_init.cc:61 ((UBSAN_MODE_UNKNOWN)) != ((ubsan_mode)) (0, 0)

:(

Comment: I cannot build a loadable sanitized .so at all on my home computer, so this will have to wait until I get to my other computer.

Comment: OK found the problem, here's what I do: (1) build the shared lib: `clang++ -fPIC -o simpledll.so -fsanitize=undefined simpledll.cpp -shared -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` (2) build the executable: `clang++ -rdynamic -o dlopen  dlopen.cpp -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -Wl,-rpath=. -L /usr/lib/clang/4.0.1/lib/linux/ -Wl,--whole-archive  -lclang_rt.ubsan_standalone_cxx-x86_64 -lclang_rt.ubsan_standalone-x86_64 -Wl,--no-whole-archive -stdlib=libc++ -pthread -lrt -ldl` (3) error message: `simpledll.cpp:3:4: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1000 cannot be represented in type 'int'`

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!